# Bitfields bigger than a long long?

Tags: c, data-structures

Is it possible to declare a bitfield of very large numbers e.g.

```
struct binfield{
    uber_int field : 991735910442856976773698036458045320070701875088740942522886681;
}wordlist;
```

just to clarify, i'm not trying to represent that number in 256bit, that's how many bits I want to use.  Or maybe there aren't that many bits in my computer?

Comment: There aren't that many bits in all computers on earth together.

Comment: @interjay all computers in the world don't have more than 256 bit?

Comment: @Philipp All computers in the world don't have 991735910442856976773698036458045320070701875088740942522886681 bits.

Comment: To expand on @interjay, if every single bit was stored in a single hydrogen atom, this hypothetical computer would weigh 827,651.5 times the mass of the sun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C does not support numeric data-types of arbitrary size. You can only use those integer sizes which are provided by the compiler, and when you want your code to be portable, you better stick to the minimum guaranteed sizes for the standardized types of `char` (8 bit), `short` (16 bit), and `long` (32 bit) and `long long` (64 bit).

But what you can do instead is create a `char[]`. A char is always at least 8 bit (and is not more than 8 bit either except on some very exotic platforms). So you can use an array of char to store as many bit-values as you can afford memory. However, when you want to use a char array as a bitfield you will need some boilerplate code to access the correct byte.

For example, to get the value of bit `n` of a char array, use

```
bitfield[n/8] >> n%8 & 0x1
```

Comment: There are historical platforms where `char` is *not* eight bits, and the specification doesn't say that `char` has to be eight bits. However, `sizeof(char)` will always give you `1` no matter the number of bits in a `char`.

Comment: To add to @JoachimPileborg's comment and in case you care about the small chance of a non-8 bit `char`: the C standard says that `char` will always be at least 8 bits, and the number of bits in `char` is provided in the `CHAR_BIT` macro (from `limits.h`).  POSIX does specify that `CHAR_BIT` is exactly 8.

Comment: the char technique seems like the right way to go about it, although I realize storing so may be a while until moore's law catches up